# Notepad++ Replacing text between two points with different characters?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have this text:

```
D5 0.25 8;0.25 E5 0.25 8;0.5 F#5 1 8;1.5 E5 1 8;2.5 D5 1 8;3.5 B4 1 8;4.5 A4
```

Except, it's 800 characters long... For example, I would like to get the text between D5 and E5 and replace it with a single space. So it looks like this
D5 E5, but as I said there are different values between each one.

Answer (score 3):

As long as "D5" and "E5" do not appear inside the block, you can use Regular Expressions:

Search for: `D5.*?E5`
Replace with: `D5 E5`

Remember to enable regular expression search mode

Answer (score 0):

Given that I recognize this as MIDI data, I assume you want to remove all midi data except for their notes, separated by a space.

You will want to use the following regex pattern for that:

Seach for `([A-Z]#*.).+?;.+?`  (note the space at the end. I used ALT+255 because SuperUser removes it otherwise.)
And replace for: `\1`  (also note the space at the end, also ALT+255 there.)

It will make all replacements except for the very last note, unless there's a space at the end too.

The regex explained:

```
(                - Start Capture group
  [A-Z]          - Search for any char between A and Z, exactly 1 time
  #*             - Search for a # 0 or more times
  .              - Search for any character exactly 1 time.
)                - End capture group
                 ------------------
                 The above search will result in the midi note, eg A3 and store it in \1

.+?              - Continue to search for any character 1 or more times in non-greedy way.
;                - Search until we find the first ;
.+?              - Search for any character 1 or more times in non-greedy way.
                 - search until we find a space.
```